# how to load and launch .app file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, launch, .app

How to load and launch .app executable of other project in my project **without URL based?**

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're jailbroken, the ONLY way to launch an app on the phone is with a URL scheme.